# Добавление модели (Relationships Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

Три таблицы.
`users`, `verification_types`, - хранит id, name и slug. Например, `id` = 1, `name` = 'Подтверждённый', `slug` = 'verificated'. `users_verifications` - `id`, `user_id` (связь с `` users`.`id ``), `verification_id` (связь с `` verification_types`.`id ``.

Хочу, чтобы при регистрации пользователя, можно было одной строчкой добавить запись в таблицу `users_verifications` запись по типу: `id` = USER_ID, `verification_id` = 1
Можно ли как-то параллельно записать данные путём отношений таблиц?
Имеются миграции, помимо стандартной таблицы `users`:

**Таблица `verification_types`** *(Уровни верификации по типу: 1 = Гость, 2 = Подтвержден E-Mail и т.д.)*

```php
Schema::create('verification_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->comment('Название уровня верификации');
        $table->string('slug')->comment('Системное название');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Таблица `users_verifications`** *(Верификации по типу: **user_id:1**, **verification_id:3** = Подтверждён номер и E-Mail и т.д.)*

```php
Schema::create('users_verifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->comment('ID пользователя');
        $table->integer('verification_id')->unsigned()->comment('ID типа верификации');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('verification_id')->references('id')->on('verification_types')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

---

**Модель `VerificationTypes`**

```php
class VerificationTypes extends Authenticatable 
{
    ...

    public function userVerification() {
        $this->belongsToMany('App/User');
    }
}
```

**Модель `User`**

```php
class User extends Authenticatable 
{
    use Notifiable;
    use HasRoleAndPermission;

    ...

    /**
     * User -> Тип верификации
     */
    public function verificationStatus() {
        $this->belongsToMany('App\Entities\User\VerificationTypes', 'users_verifications', 'user_id', 'verification_id');
    }
}
```

---

**Контроллер `RegisterController`**

```php
class RegisterController extends Controller
{

...

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);

        $role = Role::where('slug', '=', 'guest')->first(); // Прикрепляем роль к пользователю
        $user->attachRole($role);

        /*
         * Прикрепляем уровень верификации
         */
        $user->verificationStatus()->attach([$user->id, 1]);

        return $user;
    }
}
```

Заранее спасибо!

Версия Laravel: 5.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправлено!
Ошибка была в том, что забыл в моделях `return`.

Потом, в таблицу добавлялись две записи. `id=USER_ID, verification_id=1` и `id=USER_ID, verification_id=USER_ID`
Тогда просто вместо

```
$user->verificationStatus()->attach([$user->id, 1]);
```

Сделал:

```php
$user->verificationStatus()->attach([1]);
```